# Passing <img src=""> trough param on Ajax buggy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I built a simple web chat using jquery, then I implemented an icon adder, the thing is that when im passing trough Ajax the text in the input with the icons sometimes it adds the images sometimes it does not , for example if sending only icons it works, but if for example I write text and give spaces it does not appear anymore.

Im using an contenteditable="" div for the text, then im reading it trough a js variable,  all is good till I try to pass the param

```
$( "#send" ).click(function() {
    var mensagem = document.getElementById("inputx").innerHTML;
    //var mensagem = mensagem.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-')
    var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>";
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'scripts/insert_chat.php',
            data:'username='+username+'&mensagem='+mensagem,
            success: function(){
                // handle response here.
                // you can still access the open variable here!
            }
    });
});
```

This is the insert_chat.php:

```
<?php
require_once("../configs/database.php");
$connect = new mysqli($config['database']['host'],$config['database']['user'],$config['database']['pass'],$config['database']['db']);  
global $connect;

$mensagem =  $_POST['mensagem'];
$url = "http://milestone.gm-tests.xyz";
/*$mensagem = str_replace(array('"..','png/"'), array("..","png"), $mensagem);
$mensagem = str_replace('\"','', $mensagem);
*/
$email = $_POST['username'];

$getu = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$fetch = $getu->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$username = $fetch['username'];
$user_id = $fetch['id'];

$insert = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO chat
                            (username,user_id,mensagem) 
                            VALUES(?,?,?)");

$insert->bind_param("sis", $username,$user_id,$mensagem);
if($insert->execute()){ 
}else{  
    echo $connect->error; 
}
```

Comment: This is most likely due to how the HTML string is being encoded/decoded when saved and retrieved. Also note that is a really bad idea - you're leaving your website wide open to XSS attacks.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know it makes it vulnerable, but it's for an internal platform of a company so the purpose is not to hack in but just communicate, any clue on how to fix it? Encoding at db is utf8

Comment: I mean HTML encoding, not character encoding. Check the database. If the HTML is stored something like `%3Cimg+%2F%3E` or `&lt;img /&gt;` then you need to decode it when sending it back to the client.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Well it goes good into the database, images for example go as <img src"\blabla\" ... The thing is that some times it does not even add to database the image, for example when sending text and icon it does not submit image to db, only with basic words

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan after testing precisely I discovered that it only does not add it if I place a space between the text and the icon

Comment: You are using a prepare for the messages, but not using one for grabbing the customer information.  Question, how long is a mensagem?

Comment: @NiteRain What you mean with a prepare for the messages? PHP query prepare? But im grabbing customer information, username and user_id.. A message can be as long as you please